# Why does this limit approach $e$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Why does
 $$(1+1/k)^{k}\rightarrow e\hspace{0.5cm}\text{as}\hspace{0.5cm}k\rightarrow\infty$$

why does it not approach

$$(1+1/k)^{k}\rightarrow (1+0)^k=1\hspace{0.5cm}\text{as}\hspace{0.5cm}k\rightarrow\infty$$

Comment: This is just true by definition, that is to say this is one of several equivalent **definitions** of the number $e$

Comment: For a fixed finite $k$, expand $(1 + \frac{1}{k})^k$.

Comment: Presumably the question is then: if you define $e$ this way, why is $e \neq 1$?

Comment: I do not like the fallback of explaining things "by definition", but thanks for trying cpiegore. It seems like jim is going somewhere, but i cant see how expanding for a fixed finite k would help explain, we would just get $(1)(1)(1)...$ Ian hit the nail on the head.

Comment: We could observe that it is more like ${(1+\epsilon)}^k$ for a small $\epsilon <0$. If we take a number which is a little bit greater then $1$ to the $k$-th power then the result is not 1.

Comment: @helpmeh Your second statement is not correct.  You need to substitute $\infty$ for **EVERY** use of $k$.  If you do this you get $1^\infty$ which is indeterminate.

Comment: @K.Hoffmann I think you should actually have $\epsilon > 0$.  If $\epsilon < 0$ than the answer is $0$

Comment: @cpiegore thank you for the correction here

Comment: You can't separate limits in pieces like that.  Otherwise $(1+1/k)^k\rightarrow  (1+1/k)^{\infty}\rightarrow \infty$.  As for why it equals e, many will say it is the definition of e.  But that raises the question why is e the the base in which the derivative of $e^x$ is itself or why the anti derivative of 1/x is ln, both of which are alternative definitions.  The results are covered in any calculus texts.

Comment: It *is* the definition of e, (or one at least) but answering is a cop out because that raises the question "why is this definition compatible with another".  To truly answer this we need to show i) the limit exists; call it v; ii)$db^x/dx = c_b b^x$ where c is a constant based on b; there is a value of b where $c_b $ =1.  Call this value w.  iii)call the anti derivative of 1/x, ln x; prove this is a logarithm based on a value z; show w=v=z=e.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you are correctly observing is:

$$\lim_{m \to \infty} \lim_{n \to \infty} (1+1/n)^m = \lim_{m \to \infty} 1 = 1.$$

To quickly see why something weird might happen, notice that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} (1+1/n)^m = \lim_{n \to \infty} \infty = \infty.$$

In these two cases, we send $n,m$ to infinity separately and consecutively. In your limit, you send $n,m$ to infinity simultaneously and in fact at the same rate. Thus you are raising a number that is getting closer and closer to $1$ to a larger and larger power, and the two effects compete with each other to give a limit which is neither $1$ nor $\infty$.

Comment: good, concise, simple explanation. Thank-you

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that $1 + 1/k$ is decreasing to $1$ while the exponent $k$ increases to $+\infty$, resulting in the indeterminate form $1^\infty$.

The expression $\lim_{k \to \infty} (1+1/k)^k$ is the definition of $e$.

Comment: how is $1^{\infty}$ indeterminate considering 1 to the power of anything is 1?

Comment: The expression $1+1/k$ is strictly greater than 1 for $k > 0$.  It is never actually equal to 1 and the function $b^x \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ for any $b > 1$.

Comment: @HenryW. I was talking to helpmeh

Comment: Actually, the limit is $(\infty/\infty)^{\infty}$.

Comment: @martycohen How the heck did you come up with $(\infty / \infty)^\infty$.  The exponent is clearly just $\infty$ but the base is $1+1/ \infty = 1 + 0 = 1$

Comment: @martycohen Or was it just a joke?

Comment: @cpiegore $(1 + \frac{1}{k})^k = (\frac{k+1}{k})^k$

Comment: Well in any event both expressions involve an indeterminate form, so neither one has any meaning by itself.

Comment: It is $(\frac{k+1}{k})^{k} = (\frac{\infty}{\infty})^{\infty}$.

Comment: @martycohen This is what fleablood was talking about earlier.  You cannot evaluate limits involving indeterminate forms by "separating into pieces."  Different series of manipulations will give different answers, **all** of which might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting the question as why the limit is $>1$, the answer is that the sequence is strictly increasing. See [The Limit Definition of e](http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/LimitDefinitionOfE10.htm).

Answer (score 1):

By the Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 0$, one obtains
$$
\ln(1+x)=x+x\epsilon(x)
$$ with $\displaystyle \epsilon(x) \to 0$, as $x \to 0$, giving as $n \to \infty$,
$$
n\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)=1+\epsilon\left(\frac1n\right) \to 1
$$ that is
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e^{n\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)} \to e^1=e.
$$